# Docker run: uwsgi gives permission denied

Tags: docker, permissions, wsgi

This is so weid… I have a docker image that runs a web app. WHen I run it, nothing shows in containers… no error. Nothing under docker ps -a.

I ran docker events& and tried again, and it reported an error 1… which is apparently an app error, Okay.

So, I re-ran as:

> docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash -p 80:80 --name NAME -d
> NAME:latest -s

And then ran each item in the runall.sh

The first three items gave a permission denied:

> uwsgi --http-socket 127.0.0.1:3009 --file
> /var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder/main.wsgi --processes 1 --uid root
> --enable-threads -b 32768 --daemonize /var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder/tireorder.log --pidfile
> /var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder/tireorder.pid

Looking this up, and it appears to be a user permission, but all the directories and files are full access to root.

What is really freaky is that, I get it to run in windows and a mint linux VM… but in production(RHEL)) or on my linode VMs(Centos 8, Debian 10, Ubuntu 21) is gives the same permission denied!?

here's the docker file.

```
FROM lovato/python-2.6.6:latest

WORKDIR /

COPY trotta.tar.gz /

COPY runall.sh /

RUN chmod ugo+x runall.sh

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install haproxy python python-pip python-dev nginx python-paste python-pastewebkit python-babel -y

RUN ["tar", "-xvzf", "trotta.tar.gz"]

RUN ["rm", "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default"]

RUN ["cp", "-R", "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Muntjac-1.1.2-py2.6.egg/muntjac", "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/"]

COPY uwsgi /usr/local/bin/

COPY /etc/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

COPY /etc/tireorder.conf /etc/

CMD ./runall.sh
```

Here is the runall.sh:

```
uwsgi --http-socket 127.0.0.1:3009 --file /var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder/main.wsgi --processes 1 --uid root --enable-threads -b 32768 --daemonize /var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder/tireorder.log --pidfile /var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder/tireorder.pid
uwsgi --http-socket 127.0.0.1:3310 --file /var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder2/main.wsgi --processes 1 --uid root --enable-threads -b 32768 --daemonize /var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder2/tireorder.log --pidfile /var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder2/tireorder.pid --chdir /var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder2
uwsgi --http-socket 127.0.0.1:3610 --file /var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder3/main.wsgi --processes 1 --uid root --enable-threads -b 32768 --daemonize /var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder3/tireorder.log --pidfile /var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder3/tireorder.pid --chdir /var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder3
service nginx start
/usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid
tail -f /var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder/tireorder.log &
tail -f /var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder2/tireorder.log &
tail -f /var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder3/tireorder.log
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post and include the dockerfile. --- On the production system, do you have SELinux activated?

Comment: Please also include the `runall.sh`-script. --- From what I see, you copy the the `uwsgi` binary, but do not make it executable. Assuming that it is executable, next questions would be: - what user is set in the dockerfile? - What is the content of `/var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder` and what is the permission of this directory?

Comment: updated with docker file and runall. fyi... I am crazy new to docker.

Comment: I build everything as root.

Comment: here is the build: docker build --no-cache -t trotta:latest -f Dockerfile .

Comment: From what I see, `/var/www/cgi-bin/tireorder` is not mentioned in the dockerfile (neither in your dockerfile, nor in the base dockerfile), so the directory should either not exist (most likely) or be empty (less likely).

Comment: It's there. The tar.gz contains the file structure and I confirmed by entering the container bash and navigated the structure. Everything looks correct... and, as I said... if I build and run the same files in mint linux, all works completely.

Comment: Then again the question: on the production server, do you have SELinux activated? And can you verify that, on the production server, in the dockerimage, the directory is also included? Maybe you are not runninig the laltest version? Images should normally eliminate the "works no my machine"-effect.

Comment: prod server has seLinux disabled.

Comment: ... and I confirmed the directory path in the container is present.

Comment: ... then I am out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: Add `RUN chmod -R 775 <your directory name>` above the `CMD` command in your dockerfile

Comment: Ashok... that fixed it. Thank you so much!

Comment: How do I mark this as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Per Ashok:
Add RUN chmod -R 775  above the CMD command in your dockerfile

This resolved it when applied the folders and the uwsgi.